# DynamoDB wait for table to become active

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a project where we are using dynamoDB as the database.

I used the **TableUtils** of **import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.TableUtils;**
to create table if it does not exist.

```
CreateTableRequest tableRequest = dynamoDBMapper.generateCreateTableRequest(cls);
tableRequest.setProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(5L, 5L));
boolean created = TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(amazonDynamoDB, tableRequest);
```

Now after creating table i have to push the data once it is active.
I saw there is a method to do this

```
 try {
    TableUtils.waitUntilActive(amazonDynamoDB, cls.getSimpleName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

But this is taking 10 minutes.

Is there a method in **TableUtils** which return as soon as table becomes active.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something as follows.

```
Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(request);
System.out.println("Waiting for " + tableName + " to be created...this may take a while...");
table.waitForActive();
```

For more information check out this link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AppendixSampleDataCodeJava.html

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented the solution for this in GO language.

Here is the summary.

1. You have to use an API - `DescribeTable` or corresponding API.
2. The input to this API will be `DescribeTableInput`, where you specify the table name.
3. You will need to do polling in a loop till the table becomes active.
4. The output of the Describe table will provide you status of the table ( result.`Table.TableStatus`)
5. If the status is "`ACTIVE`" then you can insert the info. Else you will need to continue with the loop.

In my case, the tables are becoming active in less than one minute.